# DLL not being removed during uninstall

Tags: windows-installer, gac, dllregistration

I have a msi installer that only install some dlls and policies in the GAC, but recently I noticied that the uninstall of this project was not removing some assemblies from the GAC. But, the stranger is, in some machines all dlls installeds are removed, in other machines some dlls remains and in other machine none of the dlls are removed.

This started to occur recently, and even using previously versions of the installer, that worked perfectly in the time, they now show the same problem.

Actually I'm using Wix# to generate the MSI file, but also tested this using the SetupProject from Visual Studio 2013

Answer (score 0):

Have you logged the installs and compared?  I'm betting you'll find some component reference count issues going on.   Dirty machines sometimes won't come clean.  If it comes off clean on a clean VM  I wouldn't worry about it.